# Can't install bootstrap 4.0 due to peer dependency issue

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies

Hi I am trying to install bootstrap 4 to use Angular 4.0+ new calendar feature. However when I run the command

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
```

I get these issues, which I am unsure of how to solve.

```
+-- bootstrap@4.0.0-beta  invalid
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jquery@>=3.0.0
-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY popper.js@^1.11.0
```

I know this question may have a simple and obvious answer however out of all the solutions I have viewed thus far, I have yet to find a solution which matches my problem. All help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do an `npm install` on the needed dependencies